# Centralizar uma imagem dentro da div

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Tenho uma `div` circular e uma `function` que coloca a imagem dentro da `div`.
A única coisa que preciso é que a imagem fique centralizada na `div`.

Segue o exemplo: *(visualizem o trecho em página toda por gentileza)*

```js
 function clickImagem(src)
 {
   $(conteudo).empty() //Ao clicar no produto, limpa todos os Charms presentes no Div Conteudo
   document.getElementById('conteudo').style.background="url('"+src+"') no-repeat";
 }
```

```css
 .conteudo-externo{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  z-index:3;
  background:#ff1;
  float:left;
 }
 .conteudo{
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:3px solid #000;
  z-index:5;
  background:#000;
  margin: 50px auto;
  }
  .img{
   z-index:1;
   width:130px;
                        height:130px
                        background-position:center;
   opacity:0.5;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Teste</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="https://media.dooca.com.br/forfisher.com/produto/grande/pulseira-macrame-tucunare-preta-e-marrom-14534900308000.jpg" onclick="clickImagem(this.src)">
<div class="conteudo-externo">
  <div class="conteudo" id="conteudo">
   </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução fácil e moderna é usar `flexbox`. Neste caso aplicaria ao seu `div` externo da seguinte forma:

```
.conteudo-externo {
  ...

  display: flex; /*aplicar flex*/
  justify-content: center; /*alinhado ao centro horizontalmente */
  align-items: center;  /*alinhado ao centro verticalmente*/
}
```

Em que tanto o `justify-content` como o `align-items` se referem aos filhos de 
`conteudo-externo`.

Exemplificando na sua página:

```js
function clickImagem(src) {
  $(conteudo).empty() //Ao clicar no produto, limpa todos os Charms presentes no Div Conteudo
  document.getElementById('conteudo').style.background = "url('" + src + "') no-repeat";
}
```

```css
.conteudo-externo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: #ff1;
  float:left;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}

.conteudo {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #000;

  
}

.img {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px background-position:center;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Teste</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://media.dooca.com.br/forfisher.com/produto/grande/pulseira-macrame-tucunare-preta-e-marrom-14534900308000.jpg" onclick="clickImagem(this.src)">
  <div class="conteudo-externo">
    <div class="conteudo" id="conteudo">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Links que lhe podem interessar:

- [Documentação no MDN sobre o flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)
- [Guia prático de utilização do flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)